# How do I build up logic to solve problems and further optimize the solution to its best form?

Tags: c++

I quite struggle while trying to solve problems. I'm in beginner phase and it takes lot of time for me to solve a single question, and many times those solutions are not on their best form. So, I'm always fighting with intrinsic thought to ask gpt for the solution or, best go through tutorial, hour long. Can anyone help me with how I should deal with the situation.

I have asked this question to experts, and all I get it break down the problem into small basic forms. But, the question is after I break them down how do I stich them up to optimized solution?

Your help is much appreciated..

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Just keep practicing and writing code. It's the only way.

Comment: Same way you get to Carnegie Hall. Practice. It may not make perfect, but it always makes better.

Comment: First step learn (some) C++ before starting doing questions. And then practice a lot with small toy examples.

Comment: Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: There is nothing shameful in starting with the basics. Everything big is built from smaller pieces.

Comment: Most of the time you don't need "its best form", you just need it to be "good enough". Priority 1: Get the correct result. Did you get it fast enough? Then you are done and can start solving the next problem. Often solving 5 problems good enough is more appreciated than having one perfect solution.